# A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain

Tags: iphone

I am able to test my app on my device using the development profile/certficates...

In the same way, I have created distribution profile/certicates for my app....

But when I try to upload my app to iTunes , it says "Application failed codesign verification"

Also in the Organizer, it says "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain"

i have tried everything that is listed here by other users...But not sure what the issue is...Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the little key under your certificate in keychain Access. If you do not you need to revoke your certificates in your developer account and start over.

More info here,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1618.html